Docker symfony and gd extension
I'm trying to add the GD extension to my php on my symfony project. My symfony project is configured with docker via this package https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker on windows with WSL. But when I run the “docker-php-ext-install gd” command, I get this error:

Package 'zlib', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Unfortunately, I don't really understand what I'm supposed to do.
I tried adding this to my Dockerfile:
    RUN apk add --no-cache \
    zlib-dev \
    libpng-dev
    build-base
    wget
    tar
    make
&& wget https://github.com/libgd/libgd/releases/download/gd-2.3.3/libgd-2.3.3.tar.gz \
&& tar -xf libgd-2.3.3.tar.gz \
&& cd libgd-2.3.3 \
&& ./configure --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
&& make \
&& make install \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd zlib

But it doesn't seem to work. Thank you for your help.

What happen if you try to add zlib1g-dev?

Yes, it's works with this library :D thank you !

Ty for your feedback, I post an answer from my comment

As mentioned in this issue, the zlib1g-dev is missing.
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    zlib-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \ 
    libpng-dev \
    build-base \
    wget \
    tar \
    make \
&& wget https://github.com/libgd/libgd/releases/download/gd-2.3.3/libgd-2.3.3.tar.gz \
&& tar -xf libgd-2.3.3.tar.gz \
&& cd libgd-2.3.3 \
&& ./configure --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
&& make \
&& make install \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd zlib

